# I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong on this program

Tags: python, inheritance, derived-class

Define a `Course` base class with attributes `number` and `title`. Define a `print_info()` method that displays the course `number` and `title`.

Also define a derived class `OfferedCourse` with the additional attributes `instructor_name`, `term`, and `class_time`.

Ex: If the input is:

```
ECE287
Digital Systems Design
ECE387
Embedded Systems Design
Mark Patterson
Fall 2018
WF: 2-3:30 pm
```

the output is:

```
Course Information: 
   Course Number: ECE287
   Course Title: Digital Systems Design
Course Information: 
   Course Number: ECE387
   Course Title: Embedded Systems Design
   Instructor Name: Mark Patterson
   Term: Fall 2018
   Class Time: WF: 2-3:30 pm
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```py
class Course:
    # TODO: Define constructor with attributes: number, title
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = ''
        self.title = 0

    # TODO: Define print_info()
    def print_info(self):
        print('   Course Number:', self.number)
        print('   Title:', self.title)


class OfferedCourse(Course):
    # TODO: Define constructor with attributes:
    #       number, title, instructor_name, term, class_time
    def __init__(self, number, title, instructor_name, term, class_time):
        Course.__init__(course_number, course_title)
        self.instructor_name = ''
        self.term = ''
        self.class_time = 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    course_number = input()
    course_title = input()

    o_course_number = input()
    o_course_title = input()
    instructor_name = input()
    term = input()
    class_time = input()

    my_course = Course(course_number, course_title)
    my_course.print_info()

    my_offered_course = OfferedCourse(
        o_course_number, o_course_title, instructor_name, term, class_time
    )
    my_offered_course.print_info()

    print('   Instructor Name:', my_offered_course.instructor_name)
    print('   Term:', my_offered_course.term)
    print('   Class Time:', my_offered_course.class_time)
```

When I run the code, I'm getting the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 32, in <module> my_course = Course(course_number, course_title) TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Comment: Thanks for following up with my question. I got this error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 32, in <module>
    my_course = Course(course_number, course_title)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Comment: In your `__init__` for `Course`, why not add the arguments that you want your course objects to receive? In other words -- add a title and a number to the constructor.

Comment: You still have to do what it says: `TODO define constructor with attributes: ...`

Comment: And use them inside `__init__`, i.e. in `OfferedCourse` there are argument in the method signature, but you never use `term`, `class_time`

Comment: If you call `Course.__init__` explicitly, you need to pass `self` to it as well. Or, use `super().__init__`, in which case you *don't* pass `self` explicitly.

Comment: Ok, I will try the feedback provided and see if I can figure it out. New to this so it takes me sometime to get it together

Answer (score 0):

The thing is with the `def __init__(self):` method in the Course class. Here you are telling python that the class Course does not receive anything else than itself. If you want to be able to pass those arguments to init, but keep the default values, you can provide a default value inside init

```
def __init__(self, number: int = 0, title:str = ''):
        self.number = number
        self.title = title
```

Comment: Given that course numbers is alphanumeric string like `ECE287` do you really suggest type annotation `int`?

Answer (score 0):

`Course.__init__` is an ordinary function, not a bound method, so you need to pass `self` explicitly:

```
class OfferedCourse(Course):
    # TODO: Define constructor with attributes:
    #       number, title, instructor_name, term, class_time
    def __init__(self, number, title, instructor_name, term, class_time):
        Course.__init__(self, course_number, course_title)
        self.instructor_name = ''
        self.term = ''
        self.class_time = 0
```

or, you use `super().__init__` and let `self` be passed implicitly via a bit of compiler-implemented magic.

```
class OfferedCourse(Course):
    # TODO: Define constructor with attributes:
    #       number, title, instructor_name, term, class_time
    def __init__(self, number, title, instructor_name, term, class_time):
        super().__init__(course_number, course_title)
        self.instructor_name = ''
        self.term = ''
        self.class_time = 0
```

Either way, you need `Course.__init__` to accept the arguments you are passing from `OfferedCourse.__init__`:

```
class Course:
    def __init__(self, number='', title=0):
        self.number = number
        self.title = title

    ...

class OfferedCourse(Course):
    # TODO: Define constructor with attributes:
    #       number, title, instructor_name, term, class_time
    def __init__(self, number, title, instructor_name='', term='', class_time=0):
        super().__init__(number, title)
        self.instructor_name = instructor_name
        self.term = term
        self.class_time = class_time

    ...
```

Comment: when it says course__int is not defined, I'm not sure what else to change because it's defined in the code from what I can tell. Should it be my_offered_class time : class OfferedCourse(Course):
    # TODO: Define constructor with attributes:
    #       number, title, instructor_name, term, class_time
        def __init__(self, number, title, instructor_name, term, class_time):
            Course__init__(self, course_number, course_title)
            self.instructor_name = ''
            self.term = ''
            self.class_time = 0